# How to read config file in electronjs app

Tags: electron, electron-builder

It's my first time using Electron JS and nodejs. I've built a small app that reads some records from a database and updates them. Everything is working fine. I have a config file with the database credentials but when I build a portable win app, I cannot figure out how to read the config file that I would like to place next to the exe. I would like to have easy access to the file, so I could run the same app on different databases.

Can anyone tell me if what I want is possible and how? I already tried to get the exe location but I couldn't. I also read a lot of topics here but nothing seems to solve my problem (I might be doing something wrong).

I'm using electron-builder to build my app.

Thanks in advance.

Edit #1

My Config file is

```js
{
    "user" :"X",
    "password" :"X",
    "server":"X",
    "database":"X",
    "options":
    {
        "trustedconnection": true,
        "enableArithAbort" : true,
        "trustServerCertificate": true
    }
}
```

This is what I've and works when I run the project with npm start

```js
const configRootPath = path.resolve(__dirname,'dbConfig.json');
dbConfig = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(configRootPath, { encoding: 'utf-8' }));
```

However, when I build it, the app is looking for the file in another location different from the one where the executable is.

Comment: Is it possible? Yes, it is. Applications with functionality similar to this are built all the time. Can you update your post with a sample of your config file and any code you have so far as to finding the config file location and reading it into you application? Also, just to confirm, do you want to "run the same app on different databases" or "on different operating systems"? If you application runs prior to building then it should function the same after building without changing anything in the application code itself.

Comment: @midnight-coding I updated the post. I want to use the same app with different sql servers on different computers. The app is just a tool to update a specific column

Answer (score 2):

Use of Electron's [`app.getPath(name)`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appgetpathname) function will get you the path(s) you are after, irrespective of which OS (Operating System) you are using.

Unless your application writes your `dbConfig.json` file, it may be difficult for your user to understand exactly where they should place their database config file as each OS will run and store your application data in a different directory. You would need to be explicit to the user as to where to place their config file(s). Alternatively, your application could create the config file(s) on the user's behalf (automatically or through a html form) and save it to a location 'known' to the application.

A common place where application specific config files are stored is in the user's application data directory. With the application name automatically amended to the directory, it can be found as shown below.

```js
const electronApp = require('electron').app;

let appUserDataPath = electronApp.getPath('userData');

console.log(appUserDataPath );
```

In your use case, the below would apply.

```js
const electronApp = require('electron').app;

const nodeFs = require('fs');
const nodePath = require('path');

const configRootPath = nodePath.join(electronApp.getPath('userData'), 'dbConfig.json');

dbConfig = JSON.parse(nodeFs.readFileSync(configRootPath, 'utf-8'));

console.log(configRootPath);
console.log(dbConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [electron-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-store) to store config.

Electron doesn't have a built-in way to persist user preferences and other data. This module handles that for you, so you can focus on building your app. The data is saved in a JSON file named config.json in app.getPath('userData').